# Laravel auth won't let me "get" from Database

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

So I've cloned my own laravel project, that works on my main machine, to my test pc and set it up as follows:

1. Installed XAMPP and set it up.
2. `git clone` project to the machine.
3. Installed composer on the machine.
4. executed the command `composer install`.
5. `php artisan key:generate`.
6. I installed Postgres and set up a DB
7. uncommented Postgres extensions in php.ini
8. Edited the `.env` file to connect to the DB
9. `php artisan migrate:fresh`.
10. `php artisan db:seed`. (New users)

Now when trying to log in, the page just refreshes. I found out that I'm able to read and write to the database when creating a new page that is not protected by the login.

So something with the whole auth situation must be wrong. Did I miss anything when setting the whole project up? Or where the commands executed in the wrong order?

Oh btw. The auth was made with `php artisan make:auth`

Here is part of my `web.php`. The whole thing is really big.

```
<?php
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::get('/user', 'UsersController@index')->middleware(['auth.admin']); 
Route::post('/user', 'UsersController@store')->middleware(['auth.admin']);  
Route::get('/user/edit/{id}', 'UsersController@edit')->middleware(['auth.admin']); 
Route::post('/user/update/{id}', 'UsersController@update')->middleware(['auth.admin']); 
Route::get('/user/delete/{id}', 'UsersController@delete')->middleware(['auth.admin']);
Route::get('/usersearch', 'UsersController@search');
Route::get('/user/paginate/{id}', 'UsersController@paginate')->middleware(['auth.admin']);

Route::get('/order', 'OrderItemController@index');
Route::get('/order/delete/{id}', 'OrderItemController@delete'); 
Route::get('/order/edit/{id}', 'OrderItemController@edit'); 
Route::post('/order/update/{id}', 'OrderItemController@update'); 
Route::post('/order', 'OrderItemController@store');
Route::get('/ordersearch', 'OrderItemController@search');
Route::get('/order/paginate/{id}', 'OrderItemController@paginate');

Route::get('/customer/delete/{id}', 'CustomerController@delete');
Route::get('/customer/edit/{id}', 'CustomerController@edit');
Route::post('/customer/update/{id}', 'CustomerController@update'); 
Route::get('/customer', 'CustomerController@index');
Route::post('/customer', 'CustomerController@store');
Route::get('/customer/paginate/{id}', 'CustomerController@paginate');
```

Comment: `php artisan make:auth` this cmd is not longer available in new Laravel

Comment: @KamleshPaul Ok. So what does that mean? I started the project about a year ago. And auth was still a thing back then...

Comment: oh then you need to protect those route via `auth` middleware

Comment: @KamleshPaul They are. Well, the whole web.php is the same as on my main pc. And there it works beautiful.

Comment: that you need to debug we can't give answer based on this much information

Comment: @KamleshPaul I tried debugging. But there are no errors no nothing.  Is there anything I could show you, that would help? .env file or web.php? Thanks.

Comment: `web.php` show me and which route is not protected ? show me

Comment: @KamleshPaul When logging in, I should be redirected to /home. But when entering user, password, and submitting, the page just refreshes and nothing happens.

Comment: What you're seeing could be explained if sessions weren't working.  Sessions won't work if you didn't set up directory permissions, as [described in the installation docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation#configuration).

Comment: @Don'tPanic Thanks for the hint. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your current laravel version.
`php artisan make:auth` command is not longer available from Laravel 6.X

Comment: Version is 5.8.34

Comment: Someone suggested it could be a permission issue. But I don't know what to make of that :(